# How to reference a file from a package - JavaFXPorts

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafxports

Please take a look to the image for code reference:

[image: Netbeans IDE 8.0.2]

If you run the code above, `TextArea` displays `File Exists: false`.

**Take Note:** This code works: `ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image("icon/setting.png"));`. This means the system found the file **icon/setting.png  but not  file/reportdata.txt**.

**Why? How to reference it?**

Answer (score 1):

That's because the meaning of the string argument of File and Image is different. Please read the documentation exactly.

PS: Don't post screen shots here. Provide a real code example.